# How to implement Kobold2D KKInput gestureSwipeDirection to if else statements?

Tags: kobold2d

I'm finding it hard to learn from documentation on how I can use the Kobold2D KKInput gestureSwipeDirection to detect swipes left/right/up/down and have them carry out if else statements. Can anyone help by providing me with a sample code. Thanks

```
KKInput* input = [KKInput sharedInput];
KKSwipeGestureDirection dir = input.gestureSwipeDirection;
switch (dir)
{
    case KKSwipeGestureDirectionRight:
        // direction-specific code here
        break;
    case KKSwipeGestureDirectionLeft:
        // direction-specific code here
        break;
    case KKSwipeGestureDirectionUp:
        // direction-specific code here
        break;
    case KKSwipeGestureDirectionDown:
        // direction-specific code here
        break;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're making a mistake, you're placing the code in a single method, but you should use two hands, one to determine the KKInput, and one to check the status, plus you forgot `gestureSwipeEnabled`

try to do this:

```
-(id) init {

    if ((self=[super init])) {

        input = [KKInput sharedInput];
        input.gestureSwipeEnabled = YES;

        [self schedule:@selector(theTime:)];

    }
    return self;
}

-(void) theTime:(ccTime)time {

    if (input.gestureSwipeRecognizedThisFrame) {

        KKSwipeGestureDirection dir = input.gestureSwipeDirection;
        switch (dir)
        {
            case KKSwipeGestureDirectionRight:
                // direction-specific code here
                break;
            case KKSwipeGestureDirectionLeft:
                // direction-specific code here
                break;
            case KKSwipeGestureDirectionUp:
                break;
            case KKSwipeGestureDirectionDown:
                // direction-specific code here
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
}
```